# Finding the chest on a sky island

Tags: terraria

Playing in a small world, I explored every corner of the sky and found two islands and one lake. However, on the islands, I did not find any chests.

Is this supposed to happen? Are the chests buried, or I am just going blind?

Here is a screenshot[image]

The other one looks the same. On my treasure finder, I just see lead. Can anyone help me, or is this a bug and should be reported?

I bit the bullet and Terra Mapped it:
This is very unusual,  the fact that there is three bodies, none with chests.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. This is a bug. There seem to be quite a bunch of world gen issues with small worlds.

This bug has been reported and [here is the link](http://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/sky-island-abnormal-generation.32867/).

Answer (score 7):

That is indeed unusual. I have never seen a sky island that was not a lake and didn't have a house on it. I cannot say if it is a bug or not. The [wiki page](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Floating_Island) on floating islands would also imply that non-lakes always have a structure.

Not knowing the developers' minds I cannot say whether or not this is a bug, but it is unlikely to hurt anything to report it. Regardless of whether or not you do, you should generate a new world and see if it's floating islands are the same. I would include that information in a bug report I were sending in. After all, if it's repeatable then it's easier to figure out what's wrong.

Another possibility is that, if you got the world from someone else, they could have removed the structures before giving the world to you.

Overall the only thing you can do about it in game is to generate another world.

Comment: Added TerraMap. Looks like I will be starting a new world.

Comment: Well it is a small world. I don't know the world generation algorithms but I could see it generating random plots of sky islands that just wasn't big enough to plop down a house. The luck of the draw.

Comment: Submitted it as a bug, will choose answer after I  get feedback from the thread. http://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/sky-island-abnormal-generation.32867/ . Thanks All